# How can I match the beginning of a line with sed in null data mode (`-z`)?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I've learned that, with sed, it's possible to match the nth occurrence of a pattern by using the null data mode (`-z`): `sed -z 's/foo/bar/2'`.

How do I match beginning of lines when using `-z`?

If I execute:

```bash
echo $'foo\nfoo\nfoo' | sed -z 's/^foo/baz/2'
```

there are no replacements, because `^` indicates the beginning of the whole string:

```bash
$ echo $'foo\nfoo\nfoo' | sed -z 's/^foo/baz/g'
baz
foo
foo
```

In Perl, there is the [`m` regex modifier](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#m/PATTERN/msixpodualngc) (when slurping), but in sed it doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is not that simple as the selected answer seems to make it. First, what is the `2` (or any other number in s///2) actual meaning? It simply means that the second regex match on the line where it is applied will be changed.

In

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'foo foo foo' 'foo foo foo' 'foo foo foo' | sed 's/foo/bar/2'
foo bar foo
foo bar foo
foo bar foo
```

The sed command changed the second (2) instance of `foo` with `bar` but for **each** line that it got applied to (all of them). It could be changed to work only on one line or a range of lines:

```
printf '%printf '%s\n' 'foo foo foo'{,,,,} | sed '3,4s/foo/bar/2'
foo foo foo
foo foo foo
foo bar foo
foo bar foo
foo foo foo
```

Note that only lines `3` and `4` got changed, not all, and that in all those lines, the instance of `foo` that got changed was the second (2).

That is the way that the `s/foo/bar/2` works.

## -z

Now, if `-z` is used, lines end with `\0` (not `\n`). But the replacement works in the exact same way (with `\0` instead of `\n`):

```
$ printf '%s\0' 'foo foo foo'{,,,,} | sed -z '3,4s/foo/bar/2' | xxd
00000000: 666f 6f20 666f 6f20 666f 6f00 666f 6f20  foo foo foo.foo 
00000010: 666f 6f20 666f 6f00 666f 6f20 6261 7220  foo foo.foo bar 
00000020: 666f 6f00 666f 6f20 6261 7220 666f 6f00  foo.foo bar foo.
00000030: 666f 6f20 666f 6f20 666f 6f00            foo foo foo.
```

## mixed \0 and \n

In `echo $'foo\nfoo\nfoo' | sed -z 's/^foo/baz/2'` there are not enough `foo` in **each line** to make it possible to change the second, but in this next example: should it be?

```
$ printf 'foo foo foo\nfoo foo foo\n' | sed -z 's/^foo/baz/2'
foo foo foo
foo foo foo
```

Oops, no there are not enough `foo` at the start of the line either. The problem is: where does a line start? at a newline or at a `\0`, or both?, or none?

It makes no sense to think of "start of the line" with `^` when using '-z'.

That is an internal confusion for sed. Remember: the use of `-z` is experimental and might lead to odd problems.

## pattern space

In fact, for the substitution to work correctly, the whole input needs to be in the pattern space. No, it doesn't work if the input has NULs (`\0`), those would be treated as line delimiter (or, in awk parlance, as record separators).

```
$ printf 'foo\0foo\0foo\0' | sed -z 's/^foo/baz/2'
foofoofoo
```

We can get the whole input file inside sed pattern space by using `H;1h;$!d;x;.....` and then try the `^foo` substitution:

```
$ printf 'foo\0foo\0foo\0\n' | sed -z 'H;1h;$!d;x;l;s/^foo/ baz /M2'
foo\000foo\000foo\000\n$foo baz foo
```

The `l` allow us to see what is inside the pattern space, and the `M` flag is required so that the `^` is matching more that the first line. If the `M` is not used, the `^foo` will match only on the first line (at the start of the pattern space).

An alternative to `M` is:

```
$ printf 'foo\0foo\0foo\0' | sed -z 'H;1h;$!d;x;l;s/\(^\|\x0\)foo/ baz /2'
foo\000foo\000foo$foo baz foo
```

Please note that the trailing `\0` got removed, what got into the internal pattern space was `foo\000foo\000foo`, which is missing the trailing `\0`, which was clearly supplied on the input.

We can get all three `\0` by adding a trailing newline:

```
$ printf 'foo\0foo\0foo\0\n' | sed -z 'H;1h;$!d;x;l;s/\(^\|\x0\)foo/ baz /2'
foo\000foo\000foo\000\n$foo baz foo
```

Which is a clear demonstration that sed treats a `\0` as the delimiter sometimes, and a `\n` as the delimiter on other cases.

In short, sed with the `-z` option is still experimental.

Answer (score 7):

```
echo $'foo\nfoo\nfoo' | sed -Ez 's/(^|\n)foo/\1baz/2'
```

`^` is needed to properly count `foo` that happens to be in the beginning of the first line.

Note the code counts occurrences of `(^|\n)foo`, not `foo`. If you want to count `foo`s, but replace *only* when the desired occurrence happens to be in the beginning of a line, then this code is not a solution. For example in:

```
echo $'foo foo\nfoo foo\nfoo foo' | sed -Ez 's/(^|\n)foo/\1baz/3'
```

the `foo` being replaced is not the third `foo`.

Tested with GNU `sed` 4.8.

Comment: *the `foo` being replaced is not the third `foo`* **Yes, it is** It is the third `foo` that is at the start of a line in **the pattern space**.

Answer (score 2):

> In Perl, there is the `m` regex modifier (when slurping), but it doesn't help.

Sure it does.

```
printf '%s\n' foo foo foo |\
perl -0777 -pe 's/^(foo)/++$c == 2 ? "bar" : $1/egm'
```

We slurp with `-0777`, match a bunch of times `g` and with `m` helping that so `^` matches within the slurp, and then `e` eval the `bar` in only when a counter variable is 2.

Comment: Sorry, I've realized that my comment was misleading! What I meant it that it doesn't help in sed.

Answer (score 2):

In the slurp mode (-z) , GNU sed treats the record separator as the null value. But since in an ASCII text file there are no null characters the whole file is essentially one record or line to sed. To work around this we first change all newlines (\n) to the line separator (NUL) and then apply the s/// in t Multiline mode on the second match. Finally reverse transform

```
printf '%s\n' foo foo foo |
sed -z '
  y/\n/\x00/
  s/^foo/BAR/M2
  y/\x00/\n/
'
```

Output:

```
foo
BAR
foo
```

Comment: Why `printf 'foo\0foo\0foo\0' | sed -z 's/^foo/BAR/2'` print `foofoofoo`, then  ?

Comment: @QuartzCristal because the lines (separated by \0) donot have a second foo

Comment: But `foo\0foo\0foo\0` is exactly the same as from **your** example (after the y///).

Comment: @QuartzCristal actually in my case it's a multi line pattern space, whereas here sed sees three separate lines. The lines are NUL separated REMEMBER

Comment: sight .... Yes. i do know that the lines are NUL separated, And that is exactly what was provided as input: `foo\0`. That is a `foo` followed by a NUL remember?. But if you want to try multiline, just add the option, here it is for your review: `printf 'foo\0foo\0foo\0' | sed -z 's/^foo/BAR/M2'` which, as I already said, prints `foofoofoo` .

Comment: Your example is NOT a multi line. Why? sed in -z mode used NUL as line separator , so to sed these are three lines read one by one. Each line icontains only foo hence neither s/^foo/bar/2 nor s/^foo/bar/m2 shall work.

Comment: Well, yes, the record delimiter (knind of) becomes the NUL. But you can force a multiline into the pattern space by forcing sed to read all the input : `printf 'foo\0foo\0foo\0' | sed -z 'H;1h;$!d;x; l ; s/^foo/BAR/M2'` which prints fooBARfoo. But that happens because the `^` match both the start of the pattern space and after a NUL in multiline mode. Try: `printf 'foo\0foo\0foo\0' | sed -z 'H;1h;$!d;x; l ; s/\(^\|\x0\)foo/\1BAR/2'`.